# Restore single occurrence from recurring appointment?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007

When you have a recurring appointment in MS Outlook and you delete some occurrences, is it afterwards possible to restore one of it? They don't show up in the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The only thing I found was to change the recurrence, which restored *every* instance of the appointment. For example, add a week to a weekly appointment, save, then set the ending date back to where it was.

Comment: Worked for me on Outlook 2013 - I moved the end time one minute later and saved, which restored the deleted instance.

Comment: Any idea what you could change to trigger this if you are not the meeting organiser? There's limited stuff you can edit. I tried changing the "show as" and then back, but it didn't cause the meeting occurrences to be restored.

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can tell it isn't possible.

**If you're the meeting organiser**, I found a workaround which will re-create the deleted meeting as a single event, tested using the Outlook 2016 desktop client:

1. Click on one of the recurring meetings and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it
2. In the same calendar, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it, which will duplicate **the entire series** in the current calendar **without sending invites**
3. Open the duplicate series (the entire series) and modify the date so that it occurs on the date of the event you canceled but would like to restore
4. Remove the recurrence (*Recurrence* > *Remove Recurrence* in Outlook 2016)

**If you're not the meeting organiser**, this should work:

> If you previously declined a meeting and want to change your response, you can find the original meeting request in the Deleted Items folder.
>
> 1. Switch to your *Deleted Items* folder. You can find your Deleted Items folder in the Folder Pane.
>
>    - If your Folder Pane isn't visible, select *View* > *Folder Pane* > *Normal*.
> 2. Double-click the original meeting request in the *Deleted Items* folder. Then click *Accept* or *Tentative*.
>
> If the Deleted Items folder has been emptied, this option isn't available. Ask the meeting organiser to forward you the original meeting request.

(https://support.microsoft.com/office/show-a-declined-meeting-on-my-calendar-24e81b9b-3906-4c02-8b63-f97b02161763)

Comment: This only works if you are the meeting organiser, it doesn't work if someone else organised the meeting

Comment: @Kidburla I found some steps that should work in that case too and updated my answer. Thanks!