# Change Response to Single Meeting Occurrence in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

There is a meeting which reoccurs a couple days per week. I declined one occurrence, but wanted to keep it visible in my Outlook calendar. One way to accomplish this would be to change my status to "tentative" without sending a response. In other cases, I will want to update a mistaken decline to accepted.

But I can't find this meeting occurrence after having declined it. Doesn't show up in Sent Items, nor Deleted Items. I can't [view the sender's calendar](https://superuser.com/a/556302/534123), and don't think [copying past event occurrences](https://superuser.com/a/343734/534123) makes sense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I understand that you mistakenly deleted a single meeting in the recurring meeting and want to resume the meeting, right? If so, please refer to the following steps:

1.File>Options>Mail>Send messages>uncheck ***Delete meeting requests and notifications from inbox after responding***;

[image]

2.Double click any remaining single meeting, and choose ***The entire series***>OK;

[image]

3.Choose ***Change Response***>Decline and Do Not Send a Response;

[image]

[image]

4.Open the original meeting invitation in your inbox, and choose "Accept" again with Do Not Send a Response.

Then the whole recurring meeting will be displayed in your inbox. Hope to help you!

Comment: Was pain to find the original meeting invitation, but once I did this worked! Thanks